# "cannot open file userpref.blend@ for writing: Permission denied" in blender

Tags: permissions, chmod, blender

I'm using blender 2.69, installed via software centre, and when I save my user preference through File -> User Preferences and click on "Save User Settings" there is a message

**"cannot open file /home/ganez/.config/blender/2.69/config/userpref.blend@ for writing permission denied"**

I have checked to the path /home/ganez/.config/blender/2.69/config/ and there is no **userpref.blend** file present.

**PS:** I think this has something to do with file permission for that **config** folder and I have no idea on how to use the `chmod` command. So any advise?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same bug. I suspect it may have occurred during a recent crash, but I cannot confirm this.

You may try to rename the folder (close Blender first):

```
mv ~/.config/blender ~/.config/blender.old
```

Then open Blender. When I tried this, Blender regenerated the folder with the proper permissions.

Generally, it is recommended to avoid running programs as root. With such a large code-base, a program is bound to have some areas of undefined behavior (bugs) that even if not malicious, could be dangerous to your system.

Comment: Thank you @snapfractalpop. It worked. And +1 for the recommended way. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

OK now. I just figured it out myself for now(Answering my own question).

We have to run the program as root from the terminal.

```
gksudo blender
```

and then there won't be any problem as **permission denied**.

Comment: I just checked my directory at `~/.config/blender/2.69/config/` and there is a file called userpref.blend in that directory, which I can open from Files application with Blender as a normal user. So my question to you is, now that you have opened Blender as root user, do you still not have the userpref.blend file in `~/.config/blender/2.69/config/`?

Comment: No there is still no userpref.blend file there. All I have in the directory is **bookmarks.txt** and **recent-files.txt**. I'm using blender 2.69 installed via Software Centre.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use chown command to take ownership of the interested folder. From terminal: navigate to the ~/.config/blender folder; check current permissions with `dir -ls`. For example, in my case, the folder for blender 2.72 was owned by root. So I fixed with:

```
sudo chown -R myusername:myusergroup /2.72
```

Where myusername and myusergroup are my actual Linux user name and group.